# Remove-AppxPackage fails with error 0x80070002

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, installation, uwp

I develop an app that I have installed/uninstalled multiple times from the Microsoft Store and deployed from Visual Studio.
Now Visual Studio refuses to deploy it anymore, blocking my debug. The error message it gives is that there is already a package with the same ID installed by another user.

When I try to remove the package, I use PowerShell as administrator and run:

`Remove-AppxPackage -Package <package-name> -AllUsers`

And receive the error:

```
Remove-AppxPackage : Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor.
Deployment Remove operation with target volume C: on Package
<package-name> from:   failed with error 0x80070002. See
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
```

It seems there is a ghost instance of this package somewhere on the PC.
Are there any ways to clean this instance so I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For me, when I tried this line I received the same error as you:
`Get-AppxPackage *MicrosoftOfficeHub* | Remove-AppxPackage -allusers`

It worked when I did this:
`Get-AppxPackage -allusers *MicrosoftOfficeHub* | Remove-AppxPackage`

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: any manipulation of the Registry could break your system's configuration. Be very careful if you attempt this method to uninstall an Appx.

I was able to uninstall an app like this:

1. Go to `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\Applications\`. Look for the app's package name
2. Backup the key (right click, export)
3. Re/run the `Remove-AppxPackage -Package <package-name> -AllUsers` command

Answer (score -1):

Note `Name` of your package in the output of `Get-AppxPackage`command (it's not the same as `PackageFullName` which you use for `<package_name>`):

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select-Object Name, PackageFullName | Select-String <package_name>
```

Alternatively, just search with wildcards:

```
Get-AppxPackage *string_to_match* -AllUsers | Select-Object Name, PackageFullName
```

Then try to remove the package as below:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name <name> -PackageTypeFilter Bundle -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```